# R: Count the number of terms that include special characters (e.g. [url] in a dataset

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataset, where I have converted hyperlinks into [url] - see example of posts at the bottom. I just wanted to count the frequency of the "[url]" by using R.

I have tried the following without success:

```
data = read.csv(X: ....... ,tweets.csv)
word_split= strsplit(USER_POST, " ")
sum(stringr::str_count(USER_POST, "[url]"))
```

I have also tried this

```
sum(stringr::str_count(USER_POST, "\\b[url]\\b"))
```

The result is 0. However, when I check in Excel, it appears around 7 times. Could anyone guide me about what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

EDIT BELOW with further details:

```
USER_ID    USER_POSTS 
123        I like butterflies. 
234        I have found some information in this webpage [url] 
456        Find more information here [url]
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your data, best in a reprex format? Otherwise it's a bit difficult to account for the various details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @zoowalk thank you , I have just added further information

Comment: @RonakShah thank you, I have just added further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly this should be a workable solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_count(x, "\\[url\\]")
[1] 2
```

The key here is to take into account that the `[`and `]` characters are metacharacters in regex. If you want to match them as literal characters you need to escape them using, in R, the double slash `\\`.

Alternatively, `str_count` allows you to set metacharacters as `fixed` literal characters:

```
str_count(x, fixed("[url]"))
[1] 2
```

Data:

```
x <- "USER_ID USER_POSTS 123 I like butterflies. 234 I have found some information in this webpage [url] 456 Find more information here [url]"
```

Comment: Hi Chris , it worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it did. Please consider accepting and or upviting the answer.